# How can I save the id of a clicked image and then use it in another page?

Tags: php, jquery

After I have done a query to my database, I ouput the results one by one via images. Here is the code:

```
<?php   
            echo 'THE RESULT FROM THE QUERY IS: <br>';

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                    $image = $row['Image'];
                    $image_id = $row['ID'];
                    print_r($image_id);

                    $image_show = <<<EOIMAGE
                                <div class="item">
                                    <a href="film_info.php" >
                                        <img class="img-responsive" id="$image_id" style="height:300px; margin:auto;" src="img/$image" alt="" >
                                    </a>
                                </div> EOIMAGE;

                    echo $image_show;
                }
            }
            else{
                echo 'No results found!';
            }

            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

My question is - when I click on one of these images, how can I get the id of that image, save it and then use it in another page (in my case the page is film_info.php)?

Comment: If you're calling new page directly you can pass it as a parameter: www.mysite.com/film_info.php?url=imagename goes here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the `id` in the link to the other page.  Something like this:

```
<a href="film_info.php?id=$image_id" >
```

Then in `film_info.php` you can get the `id` from the query string:

```
$_GET['id']
```